# How can I resize a terminal screen with the python curses library?

Tags: python, ncurses

I am trying to resize the terminal screen to a specific size (say 34X107) to run a python curse based program. I'm not able to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find out how to resize the terminal window using the curses library so instead I used subprocess to automatically resize the terminal window like below. If someone has a better answer using the curses library I would still like to know. Thanks.

```
 subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/resize', '-s', '34', '107'])
```